# SQL Query to list all hours of the day in datetime format in one column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need a query that returns all the hours of the day in 12 hour format
ex: 12:00 am, 1:00am, 2:00am etc. This is going to be used in SSRS as a selection field for a parameter for time. I need to select records within a date range and then from a time range in that date range. I have this query which returns the time in 24 hour format but it is not working properly in SSRS:

```
With CTE(N)
AS
(
SELECT 0
UNION ALL
SELECT N+30
FROM CTE
WHERE N+5<24*60
)

SELECT CONVERT(TIME,DATEADD(minute,N,0) ,108)
FROM CTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: What does "not working properly" mean?

Comment: I'm not too sure, it just does not return records properly when it is in 24 hour format. It excludes certain ones and I can't figure out the reason why

Comment: the times will change, the user should be able to pick any time range they wan (a beginning and end time)

Comment: From what you explained... I think you want this to be your select statement... `SELECT CONVERT(varchar(15),CONVERT(TIME,DATEADD(minute,N,0) ,108),100)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
DECLARE @t time(1) = '00:00'; --I use 1 as when I use REPLACE later it means that I can "identify" the correct :00 to remove

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP 24 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2),
Times AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, I,@t) AS [Time]
    FROM Tally)
SELECT T.[Time],
       REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(12),T.Time,9),':00.0',' ') AS TimeString
FROM Times T
ORDER BY T.[Time] ASC;
```

Note that I return both a `time` and `varchar` datatype; both are important as the ordering of the data for a `varchar` would be quite different to start with and if you are using SSRS, I suspect you want the value of `TimeString` as a presentation thing and not the actual value.